# Skipping Devise authentication with minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, devise, minitest

I am adding some tests to my Rails app and I am finding it cumbersome to have to sign in a user each time.  I found this elegant solution:

http://www.colorfultyping.com/disabling-devise-for-rails-integration-testing/

but it seems to only apply to Rspec. and I can't seem to make that work in Minitest.

Ideally the solution is like above - disable for all tests then you can enable it back for individual tests.

Comment: this is the same in minitest. you need to overwrite the setup and teardown methods to set those global variables.

Comment: So what you are saying is I can't set it globally but need to do it in each test?